# I have search results on my page, since there are a lot I want to spread the results across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

So I have a search result on my webpage, and I am trying to make it so that when the 8th item is put on the page, I need the next page and then it continues until there are no more results, I'm not sure how to make new webpages with php. But I have no preference to whether it is a javascript or php solution. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "pass";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "DB1";



$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM DB1";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<button type="button" class="C1" id=';
    echo '"';
    echo $row["ID"];
    echo '" >';
    echo $row["Name"];
    echo '</button>';
    echo '<br>';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".C1").click(function(){
var Id = event.target.id;

document.getElementById("in").value = Id;
$( "#id" ).submit();

});



});

</script>



<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="id" action="SASS.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="dingoo" id="in">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's usually best to stick to the object-oriented form of `mysqli` and not revert to the old-school procedural style. That one is far too easily confused and messed up with `mysql_query` by forgetting a single `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pagination concept for separating multiple pages.

Help links :

https://www.phpflow.com/php/simple-tutorial-of-pagination-in-php/
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928